# SSIS 2008 error with Script task

Tags: ssis

Here is the code I write in my script task but I get the error , Name 'DTS' is not declared

1)Any idea, how to resolve it?

2)Another question, would be , instead of having 
"MsgBox(" files found)") " , I would like to send an email as an error , what should I write?

Thanks a lot

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

Imports System.IO

Public Class ScriptMain

    Public Sub Main()

        If Directory.GetFiles("C:\456").Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox(" files found)")
        Else
            MsgBox("not found)")
        End If
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to return simply 0 (it stands for Success)

```
Dts.TaskResult = 0
```

2) Change MsgBox(" files found") to something like that

```
Dim client As SmtpClient = new SmtpClient("hostname", 25)
client.Send("from@address.com", "to@address.com", "subject", "body")
```

In this case do not forget to import the namespace

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
```

I'm not sure sending will work, but you can try it

Comment: Do you have a reference to the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask` assembly? If so you can try to inherit your `ScriptMain` class from `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase`